# Problems with locate

Tags: linux, unix, locate

Wondering if someone can enlighten me as I believe that perhaps my expectations are wrong.
When I use `locate` I almost never get what I am expecting. For example... I removed a software package and ran `locate` to get an entire screen of entries that don't exist (yes, I went down the the list and checked one by one).

On the flip side... things I can see in the file manager many times don't show up.
I am confused and could use some advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

locate uses a database to know which files are where. This database is normally updated nightly as a cron job.

You can manually update it with `updatedb`

Comment: I didn't expect an answer that actually made sense. Thank you.